# How to match forward slashes or periods at end of String but Not Capture Using Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex-lookarounds

I am having problems understand how regular expression can match text but not include the matched text that is found. Perhaps I need to be working with groups which I'm not doing because I usually see the term non-capturing groups being used.

The goal is say I have ticket in a log file as follows:

**TICKET/A/ADMIN/05MAR2020//** to return only **A/ADMIN/05MAR2020**  
or if 
**TICKET/A/ENGINEERING/05MAR2020**. to return only **A/ENGINEERING/05MAR02020**
where the "//" or "." has been removed

Lastly to ignore lines like:

TICKET HAS BEEN COMPLETED

```
using regex = "(?<=^TICKET\\s{0,2}/).*(?://|\\.)?
```

So telling parser look for TICKET at start of string followed by a forward slash, but don't return TICKET. And look for either a double forward slash "//" or "." a period at the end of string but make this optional.

My Java 1.8.x code follows:

```
// used in the import statement: import java.util.regex.Matcher;
//                               import java.util.regex.Pattern;
private static void testRegex() {
    String ticket1 = "TICKET/A/ITSUPPORT/05MAR2020//";
    String ticket2 = "TICKET /B/ADMIN/06MAR2020.";
    String ticket3 = "TICKET/C/GENERAL/07MAR2020";

    //https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

    String regex = "(?<=^TICKET\\s{0,2}/).*(?://|\\.)?";
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher(ticket1);

    if (mat.find()) {
        String myticket = ticket1.substring(mat.start(), mat.end());
        System.out.println(myticket+ ", Expect 'A/ITSUPPORT/05MAR2020'");
    }
    mat = pat.matcher(ticket2);
    if (mat.find()) {
        String myticket = ticket2.substring(mat.start(), mat.end());
        System.out.println(myticket+", Expect 'B/ADMIN/06MAR2020'");
    }

    mat = pat.matcher(ticket3);
    if (mat.find()) {
        String myticket = ticket3.substring(mat.start(), mat.end());
        System.out.println(myticket+", Expect 'C/GENERAL/07MAR2020'");
    }
    regex = "(//|\\.)";
    pat = Pattern.compile(regex);
    mat = pat.matcher(ticket1);
    if (mat.find()) {
        String myticket = ticket1.substring(mat.start(), mat.end());
        System.out.println(myticket+", "+mat.start() + ", " + mat.end() + ", " + mat.groupCount());
    }
}
```

My actual results follow:

```
A/ITSUPPORT/05MAR2020//, Expect 'A/ITSUPPORT/05MAR2020
B/ADMIN/06MAR2020., Expect 'B/ADMIN/06MAR2020
C/GENERAL/07MAR2020, Expect 'C/GENERAL/07MAR2020


//, 28, 30, 1
```

Any suggestion would be appreciate. Please note, been learning from StackOverflow long-time but first entry, hope question is asked appropriately. Thank you.

Comment: Your regex looks complicated... if you just want to remove trailing slashes or a trailing dot, you could use `replaceAll(ticket, "(\\.|/+)$")`. Or I am misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: First, I was trying understand how REGEX worked, but I actually tried using replaceAll, like       myticket = myticket.replaceAll("(\\.| /+)$",""); 
and it doesn't replace the double forward slash with a blank character. So actually, there are two things I don't understand. I was about to use myticket.indexOf("//") to get the position of the double slashes and do myticket.substring(0,myticket.indexOf("//")-1) to get rid of double slashes. But still trying to understand how to do with regex. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead at the end of the pattern instead of a match.

The lookahead asserts what is at the end of the string is an optional `//` or `.`

As the dot and the double forward slash are optional, you have to make the `.*?` non greedy.

```
(?<=^TICKET\s{0,2}/).*?(?=(?://|\.)?$)
```

*In parts*

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^` Start of the string
  - `TICKET\s{0,2}/` Match TICKET and 0-2 whitespace chars followed by `/`
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline 0+ times, as least as possible (non greedy)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the the right is

  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|` because both can be followed by `$`

    - `//` Match 2 forward slashes
    - `|` Or
    - `\.` Match a dot
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
  - `$` Assert the end of the string
- `)` Close the positive lookahead

*In Java*

```
String regex = "(?<=^TICKET\\s{0,2}/).*?(?=(?://|\\.)?$)";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O25afC/1/) <sup>1</sup> | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rQtZKC)

<sub>1. The regex demo has Javascript selected for the demo only</sub>

---

Output of the updated pattern with your code:

```
A/ITSUPPORT/05MAR2020, Expect 'A/ITSUPPORT/05MAR2020'
B/ADMIN/06MAR2020, Expect 'B/ADMIN/06MAR2020'
C/GENERAL/07MAR2020, Expect 'C/GENERAL/07MAR2020'
//, 28, 30, 1
```

Comment: Wow this worked, "I did switch between using "?=" and "?:"  but never thought of doing both. This is actually a very complex regex that works great.

Comment: Thank very much I will look over this because I want to use this type of regex and other complex parsing. Great answer, Josh

Comment: @JoshCarter You are welcome, glad it works for you.